# MapView api key and app fingerprint

Tags: android, android-mapview, fingerprint

I'd like to set up an android architecture similar to how google allows access to their maps using an api key.

Something I'm unsure about is if the fingerprint of the app is sent up, along with api key, on every request to retrieve a map tile - or is the api key just sent up on its own on each request?

If the fingerprint is indeed sent along with the api key, then how does the app programatically get its own fingerprint?

Thanks,
Dom

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is your users to generate their own API-Key and use it for every request to your Service?

The only scenario in which this would make sense is if you want to keep track of who does what. In this case, you'll want to send the API-Key (which basically is your fingerprint) with every request your user makes.

Google uses the API-Key to identify who does what with their service. This makes sense for them since they life from collecting data.

My opinion on this is: If you want to offer a service that developers should use to give their apps some new functionality, it shouldn't need a API-Key. People will find that more annoying then useful. Unless you have a very good reason why you need to keep track of their actions...

Comment: The apikey is a key which is generated based upon your app fingerprint/signature. The apikey is not the same as the fingerprint. 

I presumed Google maps used the api-key architecture to authorize apps to use the maps service - not purely for collecting data.

Comment: Similar to Google maps, I want to generate an apikey based on an app fingerprint and give this key to the app developer. The app developer would use this key when connecting to the "service". However, unless the app passes the fingerprint in addition to the key, then there's nothing stopping other apps using this same key too.

So, I'd like to verify that this is what Google maps does. And also, how an app problematically gets its own fingerprint? From the command line, you'd use the keytool, but how is this done problematically in code?